# KDE taskbar dual-monitor to show applications on same monitor of each taskbar

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 (Plasma). I have 2 monitors, each monitor has taskbar. Both taskbars show the same applications, like they are identical.

Is there any way to make each taskbar show only applications on the same monitor of that taskbar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way: `Right click on each taskbar (panel) of each screen -> Settings for Windows Behaviour -> General -> Show only windows of current screen` (or something similar because I translate from my system language to English)

Comment: Please accept your own answer so it doesn't keep popping up forever as an unanswered question.

Comment: Right click -> Task Manager Settings... -> Show only tasks from the current screen

Comment: On my Kubuntu 20.04: Right click -> Configure Task Manager -> Behaviour -> Show only tasks from the current screen