# How to have the second taskbar for dual-monitor setup in LXQt

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, taskbar

I have external monitor plugged to my notebook. Notebook's screen is set to be the primary display. I am looking for ways to have the taskbar on the extenal monitor as well.

I do not want to either mirror the existing taskbar or to extend it to the external monitor. What I need is an option of having two taskbars each of which would host only buttons for the windows opened on this specific monitor.

It looks like there are solutions for [KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021947/kde-taskbar-dual-monitor-to-show-applications-on-same-monitor-of-each-taskbar) and [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124144/independent-taskbars-per-monitor).

My OS is Lubuntu 20.04 x64. So what about solution for LXQt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in Lubuntu 20.04 as well. I was able to create a second panel on a separate monitor that only had the windows open on the same monitor. Here are the steps I took to create that:

1. Right click on the existing panel and select add new panel.
2. In the configure panel menu I selected a position on desktop 2 (I chose bottom like the default that is on the first monitor). In this case the desktop number is actually referring to the monitor number.
3. Next select widgets.
4. Click the plus symbol to add a widget, select Task Manager (taskbar) and press the add widget. You can then close the add widget menu.
5. Select the Task Manager widget and click the cog wheel symbol to configure it.
6. Tick the "Show only windows on panel's screen" to enable.
7. Close the configuration windows.
8. Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it working. Perfect solution! There is no need to install any extra software. Thank your very much! I am glad to accept your solution as the answer. And, by the way, welcome to the forums. Great start :-)!

Comment: Thank you. I am glad you found the information helpful!